# Why can I not edit the text on this input element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[On this form](http://form.jotform.co/form/33307404588860), there is a button with the text "Choose file" and next to it the string "no file selected" - none of this I'm able to edit in the browser's web inspector. Why is this? Has it anything to do with that it's perhaps generated with javascript?

In any case, is it possible for me to target these to parts with javascript and alter the text? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: The style and text of this is determined by the browser. It is shadowDOM stuff. So no, while you can't edit it, you can always overlay it with a different design of your choosing, to mimic changing it. Much like what form replacement libraries (such as Uniform.js) do to make things look prettier than they actually are.

Comment: `<input type="file"/>` is native form element. can't change its style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File choosers were deliberately designed so that no part of it could be modified through Javascript. Otherwise, malicious websites could read what was on your desktop by changing the path to `C:\Users\me\Desktop` through Javascript.

Some web inspectors are implemented in Javascript. For instance, Chrome's Developer Tools is actually a Chrome extension, and built with web technologies.